# Iteration through XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I have a 6GB XML file and I'm using XmlReader to loop through the file. The file's huge but there's nothing I can do about that. I use LINQ, but the size doesn't let me use XDocument as I get an OutOfMemory error.

I'm using XmlReader to loop through the whole file and extract what I need. I'm including a sample XML file.

Essentially, this is what I do:

1. Find tag **Container**. If found, then retrieve attribute "ID".
2. If "ID" begins with **LOCAL**, then this is what I'll be reading.
3. Reader loop until I find tag **Family** with value **CELL_FD**
4. When found, loop the reader.read() until I find tag **IMPORTANT_VALUE**.
5. Once found, read value of **IMPORTANT_VALUE**.
6. I'm done with this **container**, so continue looping until I find the next **Container** (that's where the break comes in).

This is the simplified version of how I've been reading the file and finding the relevant values.

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    if ((myReader.Name == "CONTAINER"))
    {
        if (myReader.HasAttributes) 
        {
            string Attribute = myReader.GetAttribute("id");
            if (Attribute.IndexOf("LOCAL_") >= 0)
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    if (myReader.Name == "FAMILY")
                    {
                        myReader.Read();//read value
                        string Family = myReader.Value;
                        if (Family == "CELL_FDD")
                        {
                            while (myReader.Read())
                            {
                                if ((myReader.Name == "IMPORTANT_VALUE"))
                                {
                                    myReader.Read();
                                    string Counter = myReader.Value;
                                    Console.WriteLine(Attribute + " (found: " + Counter + ")");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the XML:

```
<es:esFD xmlns:es="File.xsd">
    <vs:vsFD xmlns:vs="OTHER_FILE.xsd">
    <CONTAINER id="LOCAL_CONTAINER1">
        <ATTRIBUTES>
            <FAMILY>CELL_FDD</FAMILY>
            <CELL_FDD>
                <VAL1>1.1.2.3</VAL1>
                <VAL2>JSMITH</VAL2>
                <VAL3>320</VAL3>
                <IMPORTANT_VALUE>VERY</IMPORTANT_VALUE>
                <VAL4>320</VAL4>
            </CELL_FDD>
            <FAMILY>BLAH</FAMILY>
            <BLAH>
                <VAL1>1.4.43.3</VAL1>
                <VAL2>NA</VAL2>
                <VAL3>349</VAL3>
                <IMPORTANT_VALUE>NA</IMPORTANT_VALUE>
                <VAL4>43</VAL4>
                <VAL5>00</VAL5>
                <VAL6>12</VAL6>
            </BLAH>
        </ATTRIBUTES>
    </CONTAINER>    
    <CONTAINER id="FOREIGN_ELEMENT1">
        <ATTRIBUTES>
            <FAMILY>CELL_FDD</FAMILY>
            <CELL_FDD>
                <VAL1>1.1.2.3</VAL1>
                <VAL2>JSMITH</VAL2>
                <VAL3>320</VAL3>
                <IMPORTANT_VALUE>VERY</IMPORTANT_VALUE>
                <VAL4>320</VAL4>
            </CELL_FDD>
            <FAMILY>BLAH</FAMILY>
            <BLAH>
                <VAL1>1.4.43.3</VAL1>
                <VAL2>NA</VAL2>
                <VAL3>349</VAL3>
                <IMPORTANT_VALUE>NA</IMPORTANT_VALUE>
                <VAL4>43</VAL4>
                <VAL5>00</VAL5>
                <VAL6>12</VAL6>
            </BLAH>
        </ATTRIBUTES>
    </CONTAINER>    
    </vs:vsFD>
</es:esFD>
```

How can I break from the most inner loop so that I can reach the top-most loop?

Comment: Do you want the `break` to return you back to the loop that is looking for CONTAINER elements?

Comment: I edited the question, but yes, I want to break to the top-most loop. Or just continue reading to the next CONTAINER since I won't be reading anything else from the current CONTAINER.

Comment: You can combine LINQ to XML with `XmlReader` by using something like `XElement.Load(myReader.ReadSubtree())`.

Comment: I ended up using @svick's suggestion. How can I close this question?

Comment: @user3605366 You could post your code as an answer and then accept that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using **svick**'s comment, I ended up combining LINQ to XML. Once I reached the correct element and checked that the attribute had the correct ID, I dumped it to XElement.Load.

Comment: Consider adding a little code to illustrate your point here, and try to explain your answer a little bit better. This way, it helps future readers who had a similar issue to yours.

Answer (score 4):

Using separate methods should make it easier to control your loops:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    if ((myReader.Name == "CONTAINER"))
    {
        ProcessContainerElement(myReader);
    }
}
```

In the `ProcessContainerElement` method, you can `return` when you determine that you need to start looking for the next CONTAINER element.

```
private void ProcessContainerElement(XmlReader myReader)
{
    while (whatever)
    {
        if ((myReader.Name == "IMPORTANT_VALUE"))
        {
            myReader.Read();
            string Counter = myReader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(Attribute + " (found: " + Counter + ")");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read with XmlReader and each node put to XmlDocument.

Something like this, not tested:

```
bool notFound = false;
notFound |= !reader.ReadToDescendant("root");
notFound |= !reader.ReadToDescendant("CONTAINER");

if (notFound)
    Throw new Exception("[Не удаётся найти \"/root/CONTAINER\"]");

do
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadOuterXml());
    XmlNode container = doc.DocumentElement;

    // do your work with container
}
while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("CONTAINER"));

reader.Close();
```